# Is it legal for other people (with different IDs) to share different apps,games and music with each other & if it is legal, is there a limit?

Tags: itunes, ios, applications, sharing, apple-id

Say for example there's 3 people. Person 'A' has an app that person 'C' wants, while person 'A' has another app that person 'B'&'C' want. Can person 'A' transfer these apps without any memory wipes or repercussions, and would the apps act as if they were bought from person 'B'&'C' as in for games to connect for Multiplayer and so and so forth?

Another question I have is what are the means to transfer data and purchases, is the only legitimate way via iTunes?

(I know it's not very detailed but I do appreciate any answers that can help clarify because I bought several of the same apps on different IDs and I'm hoping I can unify them)

Also, is there a limit to the number of accounts that can share an app or is it limited to one per account? Sorry to add on, but can anyone copy and paste, explain or link the rules and regulations that explain and could help with my problems?

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question. You could edit this to be about what the limits are now or what license agreements exist. You can ask lots of questions but we expect you to help keep each thread about one topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is *technically* possible, it's not *legally* possible.

As per [Apple's Licensed Application End User Agreement](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/appstore/dev/stdeula/):

> a. Scope of License: This license granted to You for the Licensed
>   Application by Application Provider is limited to a non-transferable
>   license to use the Licensed Application on any iPhone or iPod touch
>   that You own or control and as permitted by the Usage Rules set forth
>   in Section 9.b. of the App Store Terms and Conditions (the “Usage
>   Rules”). This license does not allow You to use the Licensed
>   Application on any iPod touch or iPhone that You do not own or
>   control, and You may not distribute or make the Licensed Application
>   available over a network where it could be used by multiple devices at
>   the same time.

There's more to it, but that pretty much shoots down your options there. Though each developer is free to choose his/her own wording for their EULA, so your mileage may vary.